# Bar button methods in toolbar are not calling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, toolbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have created a bar button items programatically. But the respective methods of cancel and done are not firing. 
I am adding the picker view as input view for textfield programatically. On top of picker view i placed a toolbar with done and cancel buttons. Toolbar is the subview of pickerview.

**Here is my code :**

```
(void)awakeFromNib
{
    contactAgeRange = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i = 18; i <= 100; i++)
    {
      [contactAgeRange addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }
    personGender = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Male", @"Female", nil];
    [self initializePickerView];
    self.cellTextField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.cellTextField.delegate = self;

    UIToolbar *toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,44)];
    [toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:nil action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:nil action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed)];
    UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelButton, space, doneButton, nil]];
    [self.pickerView addSubview:toolBar];
}

-(void) configureCell
{
    switch (self.cellType) {
         case ContactCellTypeAge:
             self.cellTextField.inputView = self.pickerView;
             break;

         case ContactCellTypeGender:
             self.cellTextField.inputView = self.pickerView;
             break;
       }
}

-(void)initializePickerView
{
    self.pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
    self.pickerView.delegate = self;
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self;
    self.pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
     return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
      switch (self.cellType)
      {
           case ContactCellTypeAge:
              return [contactAgeRange count];
              break;
           case ContactCellTypeGender:
              return [personGender count];
              break;

       }
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
      if (self.cellType == ContactCellTypeAge)
{
NSString *age = [[contactAgeRange objectAtIndex:row] stringValue];
return age;
}
else if (self.cellType == ContactCellTypeGender)
{
NSString *gender = [personGender objectAtIndex:row];
return gender;
}
return nil;
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if (self.cellType == ContactCellTypeAge)
{
pickerRowText  = [[contactAgeRange objectAtIndex:row] stringValue];
//self.cellTextField.text = pickerRowText;
}
else if (self.cellType == ContactCellTypeGender)
{
pickerRowText = [personGender objectAtIndex:row];
//self.cellTextField.text = pickerRowText;
//[self.cellTextField endEditing:YES];
}
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
 {
if (self.setNextResponderActionBlock)
 {
self.setNextResponderActionBlock();
}
return YES;
}

-(void) cancelButtonPressed
{
[self.cellTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void) doneButtonPressed : (id)sender
{
if (self.cellType == ContactCellTypeAge)
{
self.cellTextField.text = pickerRowText;
}
if (self.cellType == ContactCellTypeGender)
{
self.cellTextField.text = pickerRowText;
}
 }
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't tried to run your code, but it looks like either (1) your toolbar view is getting set behind some subview of the picker (UIPickerView has a lot of internal stuff going on), thus touch events are not reaching it or (2) your view controller is not part of the responder chain for the picker. In the case of (2), try setting target to "self" instead of "nil" when you set up your toolbar items.

Comment: Even after setting the target to self, I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

**configureCell** in this Method add `self.cellTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is xib cell. So when I add subview to the xib it displays multiple times where ever I am using the cell. By the way how can I  get the toolbar height.

Comment: I am using the cell for 5 times in a tableview. In first two cases I want pickerview as input view for text field in the xib.

Comment: I don't want to click on the cell. I want to click on the textfield in the cell. So no need of didselectrow method

Comment: Above is the complete code of my cell xib and the xib contains only a label and a textfield